# Facebook Like Button Not Displaying: "No polyfill registered for object"

Tags: facebook, drupal, drupal-7, facebook-like

I have been working on a Drupal website and it went live around a week ago. Everything was going pretty much dandy until I just noticed today that Facebook like buttons have stopped showing. I am using this code (as generated by the like button generator on Facebook):

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_GB/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=331116490288120";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
```

You can view the website here: http://www.theladbible.com/ (the like button is to the left of the Twitter button).

When looking in my debugger console on Chrome I get the following error twice:

```
Uncaught Error: No polyfill registered for object
```

I have looked at other posts on SO but none of them had answers, a recent post on a Drupal forum showed that adding a locale helped for their plugin, but that isn't an option with this method I believe?

Hope someone can help, cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This probably related to new bug that was today introduced: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/420667497951980

Facebook Platform Status confirm this:

> **JS SDK issues** today (2012 May 9) at 2:42pm
>   Currently, the all.js file is throwing an exception on load. We are working on a fix now. For more information and updates, please subscribe to bug [420667497951980](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/420667497951980).

This is also may be not related to that bug but other functionality, if you use something that removed from JS-SDK like `FB.Data.*` (today I've fixed exactly the same issue in one of my apps that had `FB.Data.query`/`FB.Data.wait` in the code, and that functionality deprecated for some time and was just removed from SDK).

Comment: That looks like it could be the issue, I have seen on some other websites while looking into it that some sites have switched to using the old share button, possibly as a temporary measure.

I think this could be the correct answer to be honest and is a problem at their end. Would upvote but currently need more rep. Thanks Juicy!